# Jsonarray object to string

Tags: android, arrays, http, object

```
List<String> getid = new ArrayList<>();
String mainChapterNumber;
JSONArray user = ProkatonHttpClient.things(name, radius, free, x, y, limit, offset, orderBy, desc);
for (int i = 0; i < user.size(); i++) {
    getid.add(((JSONObject)user.get(i)).get("id").toString());
}
```

Im getting id by this code. "id" - int.
How can i get "location" Object {x: float, y: float} and parce it to string x and string y as i do it with id ?

Comment: What is your Json Rsponse ?

Answer (score 0):

Now Check This It is working Code Hope this might help

**Edit**
I think this is the correct way to convert any double value into string.

```
JSONArray user = new JSONArray(JSONSTRING);
    JSONObject obj = user.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject json = obj.getJSONObject("location");
    String x = String.valueOf(json.getDouble("x"));
    String y = String.valueOf(json.getDouble("y"));
```

Comment: im using jsonsimple by the way. And "user" cant resolve method getJSONObject().